# Moving angular2 app to glassfish from VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, glassfish, angular, config, systemjs

I'm having a problem with SystemJS configuration

I have a working angular2 app in VS2015 (asp.net core 1.0). I can compile the .ts files and make changes and no errors occur.

I would now like to move the app into a glassfish 4.1 web project (acting as a production server) but when I move the entire wwwroot contents 
(all the .js) from VS2015 over to the glassfish web folder I am presented with numerous 404's.

here is the the Index.html file that I am using in VS2015:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />
    <title>Procurement v1.0</title>
    <link src="libs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="libs/css/case1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                '@ngrx/store': {
                    main: 'index.js',
                    format: 'cjs'
                }
            },
            map: {
                '@ngrx/store': 'libs/storedist'
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script> 
        System.import('appScripts/app')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <router-app>Loading...</router-app>
</body>
</html>
```

When I copied the wwwroot contents over to Glassfish I needed to prefix all of scripts with the name of the Web archive (APPOCase1a) for the scripts to be recognized. I also had to use a CDN for system.js as it wasn't being recognized at all. I also had to change the System.import to point to the actual application .js file for it to be recognized, resulting in the following index.html on Glassfish:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />
    <title>Procurement v1.0</title>
    <link href="/APPOCase1a/libs/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/APPOCase1a/libs/css/case1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/APPOCase1a/libs/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                 '@ngrx/store': {
                    main: 'index.js',
                    format: 'cjs'
                }
            },
            map: {
                '@ngrx/store': 'libs/storedist'
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script> 
        System.import('/APPOCase1a/appScripts/app.js')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <router-app>Loading...</router-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I'm seeing in the browser's console:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/product/product-home.component 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/home/home.component 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/po/po-generator-home.component 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/vendor/vendor-home.component 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/store/reducers 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/APPOCase1a/appScripts/product/product-home.component(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
system.src.js:4597 GET http://localhost:8080/libs/storedist/index.js 404 (Not Found)I @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:589(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
```

Since I'm a noob on this stuff, I'm wondering if there is an easier way to port this app, or fix the configuration. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with this for a few hours I discovered it was the

```
<base href="/">
```

tag that was screwing me up. After removing this the app partially works now but I'm still getting the 404 on html templates and img files now. I'll investigate further.